# Does MPAndroidChart support stacked bar charts?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

I reasrched a lot about compound graphs in [MPAndroidChart](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) library. By compound graph i mean having multiple types of graph  series in single plot.

I tried other libraries too like androidplot , achartengine library..
Although they provide compound graphs but they  dont provide that much flexibility (like adding marker view/toast) .

**My Expectation**

```
1. i want both stacked bar chart and line chart in single graph 
2. I need 2 y-axis(one at right and other at left)
```

is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

1. Stacked-BarCharts are supported (as of v3.0.0 also in combination with LineChart)
2. 2 YAxis are supported (left and right)